# Understanding ssh-keygen for SSH'ing into a server vs accessing GitHub

Tags: git, github, ssh, ssh-keygen

So my understanding is that `ssh-keygen` is one of many commands provided by OpenSSH.

When generating a private/public key pair using `ssh-keygen`, I know that you can put the public key onto a remote server (inside `~/.ssh/authorised_keys`) and it'll allow you to ssh into that server.

But it seems like there are two different ways of generating the key pair though, in the sense that you can just use `ssh-keygen` alone, and when you `cat` the public key you'll see something like:

```
ssh-rsa XXXX User@ComputerName
```

Where `User@ComputerName` looks something like `M@Marks-MBP.default` for me.

The other way is using the `-C` comment flag (GitHub suggests doing this). Where it seems that it'll not use `User@ComputerName` but your email address instead in its place (or whatever 'comment' you happen to use).

Am I right in thinking that for SSH'ing into a server, the username you use to login is whatever the `-C` comment is set to in your public key?

So if I don't use `-C` at all, then it'll generate a public key with `M@Marks-MBP.default` at the end. I then assume the username would be `M`.

But if I use `-C "bingbop"`, then I assume the username to SSH would be `bingbop`.

Is that correct?

Also, is there any technical reason GitHub suggest using `-C` to specify your email address rather than leaving that flag off?

I'm guessing that when you try to clone or push to your repo (using their `git@github.com:<user>/<repo>.git` protocol) that it can't identify you by the public key alone, it needs the comment to be set to your GitHub email address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am I right in thinking that for SSH'ing into a server, the username you use to login is whatever the -C comment is set to in your public key?

No. The key's comment field is really just that: An (optional) comment, which by convention usually is set to your email address, but happens to default to `user@host` if not specified.

The username you use when logging in via SSH is not related to or derived from that comment field.

> Also, is there any technical reason GitHub suggest using -C to specify your email address rather than leaving that flag off?

Yes, the reason being that the default of `user@host` rarely provides useful information to someone you give your public key to. Your email address on the other hand is more valuable information.

> I'm guessing that when you try to clone or push to your repo (using their git@github.com:/.git protocol) that it can't identify you by the public key alone, it needs the comment to be set to your GitHub email address.

GitHub *can* identify you by the provided key alone as it is unique across all GitHub users. In the URI syntax you've given, the `git` before the `@` is the username provided to SSH. So GitHub uses a generic username of `git` for all its users, and individual users are identified by the key they provide.

Comment: Thanks @sschuberth. Out of interest I was reading http://sshkeychain.sourceforge.net/mirrors/SSH-with-Keys-HOWTO/SSH-with-Keys-HOWTO-4.html and it seemed to indicate (although not actually mentioned; it was just the impression I got) that the username you use with the ssh command was somehow tied to the `user@host` in the SSH public key

Comment: OK I think I see where I was getting confused. Reading https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2 it seems to suggest that you'll always need to have a user account created regardless, and then your ssh key pair just prevents you from having to enter the password for that user

Comment: Yes, that's how it usually is: For a server at `host` that has an account for `user` configured you would use `user@host` to login. However, for huge sites with tens or hundreds of thousands of users not each user really has an account on the server, but there is only one account (e.g. named `git`) which is "shared" for all users in terms of SSH authentication, but still users are identified by the key they provide.

Answer (score 1):

The comment is for informational purposes only; it has no relevance to the username known by Git. When you ssh into github, it matches the public key to the private key in your repository and as such knows which user to associate with by that only.

Comment: So with regards to SSH'ing into a standard web server (i.e. where you add the public key into the authorized_keys file) how do you know what username to use when using the ssh command? Or does it not matter (e.g. you could use any username, it'll ignore it and use the private/public key to authenticate you)

Comment: How GitHub sets up their authentication is orthogonal to how other servers set up their authentication. In GitHub's case you're always going in as the userid `git`. For other servers you need to put the user when you do the connection. You can set up separate identities in the `.ssh/config` on the client side, such that the client serves a smaller set of identities; but it's not the case in general that `ssh` means 'any user'.

Comment: @Integralist There is *no* concept of usernames when SSHing using a public/private keypair. The key alone is what you authenticate with. (You can instead SSH using a username and password, but this is a totally separate concept, and would be used instead of a keypair). That comment at the end of the key, like AlBlue says, is not a username – it is simply a description/comment that you can, if you want, use to help you know whose key that is.